# What are each part of macros named in the C standard?

Tags: macros, terminology

I am writing an academic paper related to the C language, but I am pretty confused about the terminology and afraid that the word I used is not complied with the standard.

For example,

```
#define AREA_CIRCLE(radius) (M_PI * radius * radius)
|<-----------------------A------------------------>|
|<-B->| |<---C--->| |<D >|  |<----------E--------->|

printf("%f\n", AREA_CIRCLE(1024));
               |<------A'----->|
               |<---C'-->| |E'|
```

I am not so sure, but I guess that

```
A:  macro definition
B:  macro directive (preprocessor directive)
C:  macro name
D:  macro parameter
E:  macro substitution rule
A': macro ???
C': macro ???
E': macro argument
```

What does the accurate terminology that would not make them ambiguous for the readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard, Sec. 6.10.3, §9, the name of the macro is also called macro name when it is used for replacement. In the definitions part of the standard, more specifically in Sec. 3.3, it is stated that the function-like construction you show in your question is a "macro invocation". So

```
printf("%f\n", AREA_CIRCLE(1024));
               |<------A'----->|
               |<---C'-->| |E'|
```

`A'`: macro invocation
`C'`: macro name
`E'`: [macro] argument